# Migrate from ASP.NET with Razor pages to a separate frontend and backend

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, razor

Currently my application contains one wrapper page which then renders the other pages depending on the current view.

I would like to migrate from ASP.NET MVC 5 with Razor pages to two separate projects, one for the frontend (SPA without Razor pages but JavaScript) and one backend (with ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI).
Additionally the backend should not be concerned, what frontend is used, so it is possible to switch the frontend in the future.

Is this possible to do and what approaches are there to do such a migration?

Comment: Yes, you should do that.
Use Angular or similar for frontend and .net for backend...
This link is a bit old, but can be good starting point

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/26/build-crud-app-aspnetcore-angular

Comment: @onedevteam.com The problem is not if I should do it, but what steps I have to take, to migrate the content of the Razor pages into a separate project with Angular or a similar framework.

Comment: From my knowledge, there is no way to migrate razor pages to angular.
Only way is to rewrite frontend from scratch...
Maybe you can reuse parts of code, but manual is only way so far...